PyTorch in C++ - how to get part of tensor for all dimensions?
I have the following tensor operation in Python:
A = A[
      :,
      h_offset:h_offset + fineSize,
      w_offset:w_offset + fineSize
    ]

where *_offset and fineSize are some integers. I am looking for a way to do the same operation in libtorch C++.
According to this question and the provided answers I should use Slice(). However, I have a problem wrapping my head around the Tensor::slice() call.
In the Python code, the first part basically translates to all dimensions. In my case I am using an cv::Mat (OpenCV) and A is originally defined as
auto tensor_input = torch::from_blob(img_torch.data, { 1, img_torch.size().height, img_torch.size().width, 1 }, torch::kFloat32);

with img_torch being the cv::Mat image. Alone here I am confused how to translate the all dimensions  to C++ since the Tensor::slice() function expects dim (dimension) as its first argument:
Tensor::slice(int64_t dim, int64_t start, int64_t end, int64_t step)

Do I need to slice on a per-dimension basis and then merge the results? E.g.
A_w_slice = A.slice(2, w_offset, w_offset + fineSize, 1);
A_h_slice = A.slice(3, h_offset, h_offset + fineSize, 1);

I pick 2 and 3 since I have 1, w, h, 1 based on the torch::from_blob() call.
I am not really familiar how such operations work under the hood and if the slicing is just creating a reference to the subset of the original memory used by the tensor we are slicing or a copy is made. If the latter, wouldn't this be very inefficient?

torch::slice works here but I think torch::narrow is clearer. No need to merge anything, just slice in one dimension, then slice the result along the other dimension.
A_w = A.narrow(/*dim=*/1, /*start=*/w_offset, /*length=*/finesize);
A_hw = A_w.narrow(/*dim=*/2, /*start=*/h_offset, /*length=*/finesize);

Note that the dims are actually 1 and 2 (the dimension indexing starts at 0) and that narrow and slice return a tensor that shares its memory with the tensor being sliced. So modifying A_hw will modify A itself.
And because there is no copying required, this is extremely quick, you can slice or narrow all you want
